# Performance impact of setting an inline style to the same value?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm updating an element's inline style inside a handler that fires rapidly. In my code, it's in `onscroll` (and I know about throttling), but I'll use `setInterval` here for simplicity.

What I'm asking is - does this:

```js
function updateStyle (value) {
  document.body.style.marginTop = value + 'px'
}

setInterval(function () {
  updateStyle(15)
}, 1)
```

...perform any worse than this:

```js
var current = null

function updateStyle (value) {
  if (current !== value) {
    document.body.style.marginTop = value + 'px'
    current = value
  }
}

setInterval(function () {
  updateStyle(15)
}, 1)
```

On one hand, I'm setting a `style` property. On the other hand, I don't actually change the value. My guess is that rendering engines are smart enough to notice that, but still - are they?

Comment: It's possible specs have something to tell about this case, should reread the style IDL setting rules. But anyway, it will probably depend on the implementations and thus will be hard to make a strong answer on this.

Comment: For properties like `margin-top` it might be worth to round the values to the nearest 1/4px or so, so that you don't "change" the style when the passed value only nominally changes, but would have no visual impact. To the actual queston, wether re-seting a style to the same value may trigger a reflow; sry can't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways browsers performance impact can be calculated.

**1. Repaint:** DOM visibility changes (Less Expensive)

**2. Reflow:** DOM layout changes (More Expensive)

So what your change make impact on DOM will decide your performance.
    In your case you are adding margin and If layout is changes because of that DOM reflow will happen which is expensive but also consider what large DOM you have impact on.

```
  Hope this explanation helps you :)
```

Comment: You're not understanding what reflow is... Waht we call "reflow" is the fact of recalculating the bounding boxes of all the elements in the DOM. Even if it doesn't change anything in the layout, it's just that recalc which costs an arm. Now, the question one should answer here is rather does setting the style property to the same value it already was does trigger such a recalc/reflow?